# Return Dictionary in SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am overriding the `SaveChanges()` method so that I can use the `ChangeTracker` to get the modified properties of an entity. I need to return a `Dictionary<string, string>` of the modified properties so that in my controller I can call the `Audit Service`.  So far my SaveChanges() methods looks like:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeInfo = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .Select(t => new {
            Original = t.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.OriginalValues[pn]),
            Current = t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn])
        });

    Dictionary<string, string> modifiedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var item in changeInfo)
    {
        foreach (var origValue in item.Original)
        {
            var currValue = item.Current[origValue.Key];
            if ((origValue.Value != null && currValue != null) && !origValue.Value.Equals(currValue))
            {
                modifiedProperties.Add(origValue.Key, string.Format("Old Value: {0}, New Value: {1}", origValue.Value, currValue));
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a way to access the `modifiedProperties` dictionary in my controller so I can pass that to my service?

Controller:

```
if (validator.IsValid())
{
    _workRequestRepo.Save(workRequest);
    _auditService.Log(UserId, modelId, "Work Order", "Edit", modifiedProperties);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch of dependancies here.  It sounds like it should go Controller -> Business Layer (Audit Service) -> Data Layer.  What you have is something that only controller is aware of, and any new controllers then also have to implement the same logic, that is not very DRY.

Comment: I was thinking it would go Controller -> Data Layer to save entity, then if there weren't any problems it would go Controller -> Audit Service (Domain Layer) -> Data Layer to save Audit table.

Comment: That creates dependancies on layers that shouldn't know anything.  The controller shouldn't know if it should or shouldn't audit, that's a business desicion not a presentation desicion.

Comment: Architecture aside, could you write an extension method for your DataModel that returns the dictionary and still calls `base.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: Do you think I should call the Audit Service from SaveChanges() or in the Save() method in my repository?

Comment: @chadiusvt that may work, although I think I should try to get the architecture part correct and do that as a last resort.

Comment: `Do you think I should call the Audit Service from SaveChanges()` absolutely not.  This would definitely violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  A repository should not know anything other than data manipulation.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have to call the `Audit Service` after `SaveChanges` so I know what values were changed.  If I don't call the service in `SaveChanges` or my repository where else would it go?  I'm going to update my post to include my controller.  My post is updated.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't understand why this would violate the single resposiblity principle? One of the tasks of the `SaveChanges` method would be to build the history of changes made to the entities.

Comment: Audit usually means an independant authority keeping logs of changes (key word is independant).  If tracking changes within the same scope (not independant) is usually referred to as revisioning.

Comment: `I don't understand why this would violate the single resposiblity principle?`  Because the method `SaveChanges` does not in any way denote anything other than saving changes, otherwise it should be `SaveChangesAndLogAudits()`....

Comment: @ErikPhilips I see. So let's change the name of this method, problem solved, principle happy. `public int SaveChangesAndLog() { /*.... audit procedures */; return SaveChanges(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IOC I would imagine you have something like:

(This is assume Auditing and not Revisioning)

Presentation:

```
public PersonController
{
  private IPersonBL _personBL;

  public PersonController(IPersonBL personBL)
  {
    _personBL = personBL
  }

  public ActionResult SavePerson(PersonVM model)
  {
     // if ModelState etc etc
     var person = Mapper.Map<Person>(model);
     _personBL.Save(person)
  }
}
```

Business Layer

```
public PersonBL : IPersonBL
{
  private IAuditService _auditService;
  private IPersonRepo _personRepo;

  public PersonBL(IAuditService auditService,
    IPersonRepo personRepo)
  {
    _auditService = auditService;
    _personRepo = personRepo;
  }

  public void Save(Person person)
  {
    PersonDTO personDTO = Mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(person);
    var result = _personRepo.Save(personDTO);
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
      _auditService.Audit(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Data Layer

```
public PersonDL : IPersonDL
{
  private DbContext _context;

  public PersonDL(DbContext dbContext)
  {
    _context = dbContext;
  }

  public IDictionary<string, string> Save(PersonDTO person)
  {
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>()

    _context.Persons.Add(person);
    var saveCount = _context.SaveChanges();

    if (saveCount > 0)
    {
      // Do Object Tracking
      // Populate result;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot.  I don't have that business layer though so I'm going to have to add that Audit call in my controller.  I think I have to have the `ChangeTracker` in `SaveChanges` though to get the modified properties.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to return the modified properties, you can tackle your audit procedures inside the `SaveChanges` method. This is an example:

```
    public MyContainer(IUserProvider userProvider) {
        _userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges() {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        if (entities.Any()) {
            User currentUser = _userProvider.GetCurrent();
            if (currentUser == null)
                throw new Exception("Current user is undefined.");
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var entity in entities) {
                BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity)entity.Entity;
                if (entity.State == EntityState.Added) {
                    baseEntity.Created = time;
                    baseEntity.CreatedBy = currentUser;
                }
                baseEntity.Modified = time;
                baseEntity.ModifiedBy = currentUser;

                // get and store the changed properties of the entity here
                // ....
                var changeInfo = entities.Select(t => new { Original = t.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => originalValues[pn]), Current = t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn]);

            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```